# Twilio SMS is saying a "to" phone number is not provided even though it is

Tags: python, twilio, sms, twilio-api, twilio-python

I have very simple code and I just can't figure out what's going wrong.

I have a [Twilio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilio) trial account and a trial phone number and I am trying to send an SMS using it.

```py
from os import environ
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client(environ['ACCOUNT_SID'], environ['AUTH_TOKEN'])

message = client.messages.create(body = f'The verification code for Treal is {code}', from_ = "+1**********", to = "+91**********")
```

The one in the from is my Twilio trial number and the one in the "to" is a number I want to send to. I am getting an error:

```
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException:
HTTP Error Your request was:

POST /Accounts/AC*******1830e0****a3403dfd16d****/Messages.json

Twilio returned the following information:

Unable to create record: A 'To' phone number is required.

More information may be available here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604
```

Comment: Are you sure the phone number you gave is valid?

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes. There are no asterisks in the real phone_numbers, I just added that to hide them since it is unsafe to disclose my phone number.

Comment: I understand there are no real asterisks in the real phone number, but since I cannot see the full phone number, I suggested that it might not be a valid one.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I had upvoted your answer

Comment: As far as I can see, the code you shared isn't the full code you are running, as the `code` variable is only mentioned in the formatted string. I appreciate cutting an example down, but I wonder if you cut out where the bug is here. Is that `to` number being fed from somewhere else in your code? Are you able to run [this example code from the Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python?code-sample=code-python-helper-library-sms-test&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=default#test-your-installation) successfully?

Comment: @philnash Yes, it works! Twilio's example code works! But mine does not. Here is all of my code, uploaded to a repl: https://replit.com/@nixdonut/JitteryAdolescentCubase. I used this tutorial by twilio to build it: https://www.twilio.com/blog/verify-phone-numbers-django-twilio-verify

Comment: If you hard code a phone number in the `to` argument does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does. Sorry for the late reply. I updated the code and managed to get it work for hardcoded phone number. It seems that the form field is returning a null value, there is no problem with twilio.

Comment: @philnash Twilio is sending weird messages, with strange characters though, which show up as question marks and in strange sizes and fonts

Comment: That is probably worth asking a new question about. If you can include the text you’re trying to send and an example of the strange characters, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @philnash Oh, never mind. I figured that out as well. Everything is okay now. I had accidentally mistyped one of the field names.

Comment: Oh, good! Glad to hear it’s all working now! It might help others if you were to share why your form was giving you null results for the phone number too.

Comment: Because I accidentally passed `form.cleaned_data["phone"]` to the `verify.send()` function instead of `form.cleaned_data["phone_number"]`. The field's name is phone_number, not phone. So it returned None. Thank you for responding so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a trial account, in Twilio, you can send a message only to the phone you signed in with or verified so if I provided the phone number "1234" I can only send messages to "1234".

Maybe you didn't provide a phone number when you signed up?

[Twiilo docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-use-your-free-trial-account)
[image: docs pic]

Comment: I did, but I am trying to sms a different phone number. Let me check if it works with my phone number which I registered with.

Comment: ok let me know if it works

Comment: nope. still doesn't work. The error message say the to field was absent, so I think that's it, it's not receiving the 'to' field.

Comment: I have the same code and it's working for me maybe test again if the number was verified, or test if the phone prefix is right.

Answer (score 1):

Check for hidden control characters using a site like https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php, and simply using a regular string, and see if it works or not and then work to failure.

Comment: Nope. No hidden characters.

Comment: And you removed the string formatting to see if that worked?